# How to replace column values in a pandas dataframe with regex?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to replace the the values in the column below with either 'ASUS' or 'ACER' (in caps) i.e. as long as there is the word (ignore case) 'acer' in the value, just replace it to 'ACER', and the word 'asus *' replace with 'ASUS'. I used below example screenshot from Pandas documentation as an example. I applied regex function and it doesn't seem to work - nothing happens at the output. My code:

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame({'Brands':['asus', 'ASUS ZEN', 'Acer','ACER Swift']})
dfx = dfx.replace([{'Brands': r'^asus.$'}, {'Brands': 'ASUS'}, {'Brands': r'^acer.$'}, {'Brands': 'ACER'}], regex=True)
dfx['Brands'].unique()
```

**Output in Jupyter notebook:**

**array(['asus', 'ASUS ZEN', 'Acer', 'ACER Swift'], dtype=object)**

Pandas documentation example used:

[image: Pandas Example]

[Pandas Link Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Any help with a little explanation is very much appreciated.

**ACCEPTED SOLUTION(S):**

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame({'Brands':['asus', 'ASUS ZEN', 'Acer','ACER Swift']})

dfx['Brands'] =  dfx['Brands'].str.lower().str.replace('.*asus.*', 'ASUS', regex=True).str.replace('.*acer.*', 'ACER', regex=True)
OR
dfx['Brands'] = dfx.Brands.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r".*(asus|acer).*", lambda m: m.group(1).upper(), x, flags=re.IGNORECASE))

dfx['Brands'].unique()
```

**Output:**

**array(['ASUS', 'ACER'], dtype=object)**

Comment: Can you be more specific with the conditions that you are trying to meet?

Comment: the condition is that as long as there is 'acer' in the value, just replace it to 'ACER', samewise goes for 'asus' --> 'ASUS'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```
dfx['Brands'] =  dfx['Brands'].str.lower().str.replace('.*asus.*', 'ASUS', regex=True).str.replace('.*acer.*', 'ACER', regex=True)
```

Comment: The code above helps to give the output I want but how do I approach it with regex?

Comment: The pattern inside .str.replace(). is a regular expression. 
By default regex=True inside .str.replace()
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html

Comment: oh! This is new to me. Thanks !  By any chance do you know why the example approach in Pandas did not work for me?

Comment: If you want to explicitly mention it, you can mention it. 
Pandas says in the future default value of regex will be False. You may also see the edited solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
dfx.Brands.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r".*(asus|acer).*", lambda m: m.group(1).upper(), x, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

Comment: Hi, the output I got was not what I wanted: 
array(['ASUS', 'ASUS ZEN', 'ACER', 'ACER Swift'], dtype=object).

Perhaps I wasn't being clear enough. How do I achieve just 'ASUS' and 'ACER'  ?

Comment: @snow uh, ok, I understood you wanted to uppercase just the brand

Comment: @snow edited, now it should give you the expected output

Comment: tried it! this works too. Output is correct. thanks !